# How to start single application with Remote Desktop on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

we have a new Windows Server Standard 2008 R2 (no domain, no AD) and I am tring to configure Terminal Services/Remote Desktop connection to allow start just single application and not entire desktop for cerntain users.

I am trying to do it by setting Start the following program on connection (Windows XP)/Start only the following Windows-based application... (Mac OS X Lion) in users RDP file. But it does not work as it worked with Windows 2003 server. And it always shows the entire desktop.

Remote Desktop role is installed on the server, licensing type was not yet selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [RemoteApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844(WS.10).aspx) feature in Windows Server 2008 R2. It will start a remote desktop session that appears as a single application window.

If your users are meant not to have access to other applications on the terminal server, certain Group Policy settings (including [Software Restriction Policies](http://riosec.com/protecting-windows-remoteapp-servers)) are necessary. By itself, RemoteApp is not designed to securely limit users to a single application.

Comment: I tried this. I added desired application to RemoteApp list and generated RDP file there. But it did not help. It again opened full desktop same as if I created RDP file by myself.

Comment: You need to copy the generated RDP file to your client machine and open it there. Please ensure that your clients are running RDC 6.1 or newer. In other words, your minimum client OS requirement is XP SP3, Vista SP1, or Windows 7.

Comment: I did exactly this. But I needed to edit the generated file because I need to conect over different hostname than the one pregenerated. Could this be the problem? I tried from Windows XP SP3 and Mac OS X Lion with Remote Desctop connection 2.1.1.

Comment: Please paste the generated RDP file, including your edits, as a code block in an edit to your original question.

Comment: I tested once more with the generated RDP file for RemoteApp. And it works with Windows XP SP3. But not with Mac OS X (RDP client 2.1.1). Any idea?

Comment: @user108510 If folks ask you to post more information and you choose not to provide it, you're unlikely to get further assistance with your question.

Comment: @AdrianK I did not consider it actual any more as I updated info that it works for one type of remote client. But you seem to have more experience on this forum, so I better paste it.

Comment: Here is my RDP file generated for RemoteApp that works for Windows but not Mac http://pastebin.com/ija8Ck13 I only edited line 21 to contain server IP address.

Comment: Seems that neither RemoteApp nor "Start single application after login to RD" does not work with Mac client (2.1.1). So I solved this temporarily with combination of: hiding taskbar and script that runs desirered application after login and forces logout with shutdown -l after application is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Without a domain, and group policies, I think you will find this is very difficult.

If you were using group policies, I would suggest you set this policy.

```
User Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/System/Custom User Interface
```

Without group policy, You could force every session to a particular application by setting the shell in the registry.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

The option when you are using 2008 R2 or above is to use a [RemoteApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844%28WS.10%29.aspx), but this does require that your a newer client.  I don't believe your OSX client will support RemoteApps.

Comment: It suprises me that the functionality changed so much. Was very easy to set up and use with Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Apparently it is possible to make it work on a Mac, but only by editing the generated RDP file with the current Mac RDP client: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/c3015898-cde9-450c-b6d2-e1f031dcea8a/

Comment: According to this link Mac client does not support RemoteApp, so I am confused. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/da989bf6-6df9-49c4-9cec-7b6d9fff8ab6